# webpack - serve different bundle for logged in and logged out users

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using `webpack 3.5.5` and `webpack-dev-server 2.7.1`. Have 3 different configurations for dev, test and prod. Everything works fine. Then I tried js minification with `babel-minify-webpack-plugin`. It works fine.

Please find below webpack configurations:

`common.js`

```
const config = require('dotenv-safe').load({
  path: `${__dirname}/../../.env`
});
const webpack = require('webpack');
const API_SERVER_URL = `"${process.env.API_SERVER_URL || '/api/v0'}"`;
console.log(`Will find and replace "API_SERVER_URL" with ${API_SERVER_URL}`)
const minifyPlugin = require('babel-minify-webpack-plugin');

module.exports.envVars = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  API_SERVER_URL,
});

module.exports.minifyVar = new minifyPlugin(true, {
  test: /\.(js|ts)$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  comments: false,
  sourceMap: false,
});

module.exports.rules =  [
  {
    test: /\.(js|ts)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [{
      loader: 'babel-loader',
    }],
  },
  {
    test: /\.html$/, // plugin to import HTML as a string
    use: [{
      loader: 'raw-loader',
      options: {
        exportAsEs6Default: true,
      },
    }],
  },
  {
    test: /\.(less|css)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'css-to-string-loader', // creates style nodes from JS strings
      },
      {
        loader: 'css-loader', // translates CSS into CommonJS,
        options: { url: false },
      },
      {
        loader: 'less-loader', // compiles Less to CSS
      }],
  },
];
```

`dev.js` (updated with multiple entry points)

```
const common = require('./common');
const distDir = `${__dirname}/../../dist`;

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    polyfills: '@uisdk/container/target/package/@uisdk/container/polyfills',
    main : './src/main',
    logout : './src/components/xaas-app-login'
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: distDir,
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    port: process.env.PORTAL_PORT,
    open: true,
    contentBase: distDir,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    common.envVars,
    common.minifyVar
  ],
  module: {
    rules: common.rules
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
  }
};
```

Now, question is I want to deliver different bundle for logged in and logged out users. I tried to use multiple entry points in webpack but it didn't work. The whole bundle of app will be delivered only if user logged in.

**In `dev.js` is there anyway to make an entry conditional so that I can check whether user had logged in or not.**

So, first question **is it possible ? And if yes how to achieve this ?**